# Write to string in plist dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm using a plist with structure like this: plist, array, dict key string key string /dict, dict key string key string /dict, /array, /plist.

What I want with the following code it to *set the "Done" string's value in current dictionary to "Yes".*

But now, the code *replaces the whole array of dictionaries* with the strings of the current dictionary (with the "Done" key valued "Yes" as it should, though.)

What would be the correct code for what I want?

in DetailViewController.m:

```
-(IBAction)favoriteButtonPressed:(id)sender
{

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Object.plist"];


[[detailsDataSource objectAtIndex: detailIndex] setValue:@"Yes" forKey:@"Done"];
[[detailsDataSource objectAtIndex: detailIndex] writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

The detailsDataSource and detailIndex are recieved from TableViewController.m segue if that matters.

TableViewController.m segue part:

```
    detailViewController.detailsDataSource = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:objectsArray];
    detailViewController.detailIndex = selectedRowIndex.row;
```

DetailViewController viewDidLoad

```
if ([[[detailsDataSource objectAtIndex: detailIndex] valueForKey:@"Favorite"] isEqual:@"Yes"])  {

    [favoriteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favoritedItem.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
 }


districtLabel.text = [[detailsDataSource objectAtIndex: detailIndex] valueForKey:@"District"];
```

detailsDataSource array is used like this in detailViewController so I cannot change from array to dictionary, must make a mutable copy in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setValue:forKey` is not for modifying mutable dictionaries.  You should use `setObject:forKey`.  I.e., this:

```
[[detailsDataSource objectAtIndex: detailIndex] setValue:@"Yes" forKey:@"Done"];
```

Should be:

```
[[detailsDataSource objectAtIndex: detailIndex] setObject:@"Yes" forKey:@"Done"];
```

If that doesn't fix the problem, make sure the dictionary and array are both mutable:

```
-(IBAction)favoriteButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Object.plist"];

    NSMutableDictionary *mutDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[detailsDataSource objectAtIndex:detailIndex]];
    [mutDict setObject:@"Yes" forKey:@"Done"];

    NSMutableArray *tmpMutArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:detailsDataSource];
    [tmpMutArr replaceObjectAtIndex:detailIndex withObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:mutDict]];  // make dict immutable before replacing.  Casting it ( (NSDictionary *)mutDict ) works too.

    [detailsDataSource release], detailsDataSource = nil;
    detailsDataSource = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tmpMutArr];

    [detailsDataSource writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

---

Also, instead of `@"Yes"`, you can use `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`:
`[mutDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"Done"];`
would generally be better form then using `@"Yes"`.

And:

```
districtLabel.text = [[detailsDataSource objectAtIndex: detailIndex] valueForKey:@"Yes"];
```

Should be:

```
districtLabel.text = [[detailsDataSource objectAtIndex: detailIndex] objectForKey:@"Yes"];
```

---

Also noticed that you *may* have a memory leak with:

```
detailViewController.detailsDataSource = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objectsArray];
```

Make sure to autorelease when using property setters that retain.

Comment: detailDataSource is just an array @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *detailsDataSource; so I must make it mutable yes, then I guess this will work!

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to make it mutable, change the objects, and then set it again.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But your example is a bit confusing (im new to this), can you show me what in your exaple to write in tableviewcontroller segue part and what in favoriteButtonPressed? I will update my question too so you see how the array is used else in the view.

Answer (score 2):

```
[[detailsDataSource objectAtIndex: detailIndex] setObject:@"Yes" forKey:@"Done"];
```